# RTC not Responding

Tags: arduino, i2c, embedded, rtc

I'm using a MCP7940 with a Atmega328P on a custom board. I'm using the Arduino Wire library.
When I first start communication to write the time to the registers, things seem to work fine but then in the loop() function, after like 4 seconds, I get NAKs from the RTC. I suspect that my oscillator placement is erroneous . can you guys confirm? If so what would be a fix around it? If not what else could be the problem? 
[image: RTC on the board]
C1 and C2 are 5pF, the crystal has a CL of 7pF the RTC calls for a CL anywhere between 6pF-9pF. I assumed a Cstray of 5pF.

````
#include"Driver/Inc/Seg.hpp"

#define RTCAddr 0x6F

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Seg_Init();
  Wire.begin();


  Wire.beginTransmission(RTCAddr);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0b10000000); // Enable Oscillator
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:  
  uint8_t seconds;
  Wire.beginTransmission(RTCAddr);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.requestFrom(RTCAddr,3);

 if(Wire.available()<=3)
 {
   seconds = Wire.read();
 }
 seconds = seconds & 0x0F;
 PORTD = Digits[seconds];
delay(1);




}


void Seg_Init()
{
    // Set PORTD pins to output
    DDRD = 0xFF;

    // Set PORTC pins to output
    DDRC |= (1<<PC0) | (1<<PC1) | (1<<PC2) | (1<<PC3);

    // Set PB0 and PB1 as output
    DDRB |= (1<<PB0) | (1<<PB1);

}```
````

Comment: I don't think the I2C interface relies on the crystal oscillator, so I suspect you have a different problem.

Comment: No, but the RTC does.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you wouldn't get an I2C NAK because the crystal oscillator is not working.

Comment: Try reducing clock speed, `Wire.setClock(10000);` in the setup routine and see if you run longer.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson i was thinking the oscillator was failing leading to a failure mode in the RTC

Comment: @RonBeyer Changing clock doesn't work